# Wordpress Retrieve Value from Admin Options

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I generated an Options Page for my WordPress using this tool: https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-option-page-generator/

I inserted the code my functions.php, the options page is visible, however, now I'm trying to create a shortcode where I can output the value and it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
function soonbox_date_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    
    ob_start();

    $show_date = $soon_box_options['datum_location_0']; // the value from options page
    printf( $show_date );

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'soonbox_date', 'soonbox_date_func' );
```

But on the page it's empty, shows nothing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem could come from your option value. Did you try to print a test with your shortcode? `show_date = 'test';`

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to use output buffering at this point, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `$soon_box_options` would not be defined in scope inside shortcode callback. So we'd expect that to be empty. Regardless of how you got the options value in the database, retrieving it should be standard by using the `get_option` function (See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/). I don't know if `datum_location_0` is the options key stored in the database or not, but try something like:

```php
function soonbox_date_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    
    ob_start();

    $show_date = get_option('datum_location_0');
    printf( $show_date );

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'soonbox_date', 'soonbox_date_func' );
```

If `datum_location_0` is not the key in the database, then replace that with the proper key.

Comment: Exactly that was the problem, I found it a few minutes ago. The get_option was missing. thank you!

Comment: Awesome! please accept the answer since it has the correct response to your query, thanks!